# Обновление компонентов Swing

Tags: java, swing

Имею класс, унаследованный от JFrame:

```
public class tttt extends JFrame{
    private JTable tab;
    private JPanel panel1;

    private void createUIComponents() {//Custom Create для tab
        Object[][] data1 =  {{'1'}};
        Object[] data2 = {'2'};
        tab = new JTable(data1, data2);
    }

    public void CreateFrame(){
        setContentPane(panel1);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void Refresh(){
        Object[][] data1 =  {{'9'}};
        Object[] data2 = {'9'};
        this.tab = new JTable(data1, data2);
    }
}
```

И вызывающий класс:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tttt Frame = new tttt();//создается окно с таблицей, заполненной '1'
        Frame.CreateFrame();
        Frame.Refresh();//вызывается метод, но форма никак не меняется
    }
}
```

**upd:**

```
private void $$$setupUI$$$() {
        createUIComponents();
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager(2, 2, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), -1, -1));
        panel1.add(tab, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, null, new Dimension(150, 50), null, 0, false));
        table1 = new JTable();
        panel1.add(table1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, null, new Dimension(150, 50), null, 0, false));
        table2 = new JTable();
        panel1.add(table2, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, null, new Dimension(150, 50), null, 0, false));
    }

    /**
     * @noinspection ALL
     */
    public JComponent $$$getRootComponent$$$() {
        return panel1;
    }
```

Cобственно, два вопроса: как обратиться к tab на форме и куда обращается  this.tab в методе Refresh()?

Comment: В приведенном коде `tab` никуда не добавляется. Возможно стоит показать метод `pack`

Comment: @default locale pack - стандартный

Comment: «стандартный» в смысле сгенерированный средой? Если да, то это код сгенерированный Вашими действиями и мы его увидеть не можем. В любом случае надо бы показать что он делает с `tab` и `pane1`

Comment: @defaultlocale pack, вроде бы, устанавливает необходимый размер окна. И я Вас не совсем понимаю, увидеть мы его не можем, но на него надо посмотреть. Это как?

Comment: Вы пишете, что видите таблицу в окне. Следовательно должен быть код, который добавляет таблицу в окно. Вы этот код не показали. Я подумал, что Ваша среда записала этот код в `pack` но, возможно, я ошибаюсь. Найдите весь код, который обращается к `tab` и `panel1`

Comment: а какую IDE вы используете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman intellij idea

Answer (score 0):

`tab` ссылается на объект `JTable`. Проблема в том, что при каждом вызове `new JTable` создается новый объект, а старый объект не изменяется.

По коду, объект № 1:

```
Object[][] data1 =  {{'1'}};
Object[] data2 = {'2'};
tab = new JTable(data1, data2);
```

В приведенном коде не показано, как он потом добавляется в интерфейс, но судя по описанию он отображается во фрейме.

Объект № 2:

```
Object[][] data1 =  {{'9'}};
Object[] data2 = {'9'};
this.tab = new JTable(data1, data2);
```

Здесь создается новый объект. `tab` теперь ссылается на него. Но т.к. он не добавлен на панель/фрейм, то в интерфейсе отображается объект № 1.

Что с этим делать? Есть два варианта:

1. Заменить `JTable`. Положим, что таблица находится в `panel1`

   ```
   //удаляем старую таблицу
   panel1.remove(tab);
   tab = new ...//создаем новую
   panel1.add(tab);
   ```
2. Изменить значения в таблице `tab`. Если размерность таблицы не изменяется, то можно переписать все значения двойным циклом.

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<data1.length; i++) {
       for(int j=0; j<data1[i].length; j++) {
           tab.getModel().setValueAt(data1[i][j], i, j]);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: При использовании первого метода вылетает Null Pointer Exception, возможно я что-то не объявил раннее.

Comment: @BadStudent нужно проверить, какой из объектов `null`. если `panel1`, то нужно найти в какой контейнер добавляется `tab`. Если `tab` — то значит в окне у Вас отображается какая-то другая таблица, отношения к приведенному коду не имеющая.

Comment: Добавил код, который генерирует IDE

Comment: Непонятно, что делают `table1` и `table2`. Возможно, стоит выложить скриншот и расписать подробно какой компонент Вам нужно обновить. Что могу сказать так это то, что второй пример должен обновить данные в таблице, на которую ссылается `tab`.